# How to match string?

Tags: apex

Hello I have a web service which returns contact details,but some of the incoming contact objects are not being inserted due to pincode pattern mismatch. It is expecting pincode in 'A0A0A0' format.But I want those mismatched contacts to be inserted without pincode as it is not mandatory. Now how do i compare my incoming string with 'A0A0A0' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean a pattern of upper case letter then digit then upper case letter and so on, you can use a regular expression via Apex's [Patterns and Matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm):

```
String candidate = 'A0B1C2';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]');
Boolean b = p.matcher(candidate).matches();
```

https://regex101.com/ is a good place to figure out the right pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java regex and apex "Patter" and "Matcher" objects to do this task.

Prep work

1. Build the regular expression (there's lots of web resources on that, but use the Java versions as that's what Apex does under the hood). Eg. \d+h \d+m
2. Use braces to define the parts you're interested in. (\d+)h (\d+)m
3. Turn it into a string by escaping any backslashes '(\d+)h (\d+)m'

**Write the code**

1. Create a Pattern object using your string
2. Use that to create a Matcher object.
3. Test to see if you got any matches using the Matcher's matches() function.
4. If you did, you can get the matches from the Matcher's group() function.

   `Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)h (\\d+)m');
    Matcher pm = p.matcher( zipString);
    if( pm.matches() ){
        contact.zip =zipString;
    }`

For regex to validate in java you can refer http://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-regex-validate-us-postal-zip-codes/